# How to mount an ISO on a SATA Drive so that it can be read as the VDI for VirtualBox?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, hard-drive

I have 2 apps defined for my VB; a win 7 application and a Linux Mint application. They both were originally established using USB ISO and installation software. I do want to run them both at the same time and maybe others so I don't want to run from USB media, I want to run from the hard disk which I have defined. The data is all there and I have maneuvered to it but I do not know how to mount it so that VB will see it and use it as a VDI? Still on my learners curve. Thanks,

Comment: What is the content of your ISO image?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new DVD drive to your VM.  You can do this from the VM menu by:

1. Click Storage
2. Under the "Controller:IDE" item click the first `+`.
3. Respond with adding an empty optical drive.

After you save it you can now mount two ISO's at the same time by clicking on the Storage then clicking on the one the Optical drives and selecting the ISO from the "Attributes" Menu.

You can also mount drives by right clicking the Optical drive on the Status bar of the VM and selected the desired ISO from the GUI menu.  You'll find the two available Optical drives you have configured, of which you can attach separate ISO's at the same time.

Comment: Thank you and here is an update, I have a 32GB Flash disk that I have dedicated to holding needed items in separate folders so that I can mount anything and everything. I have a 128GB Class 10 SD Card that I am evolving to but cannot get USB 3.0 connections for it so far?? This may be a waste as I have several 1TB extra drives which can be anything I define on USB 3.0, I just seek to learn more and more knowledge to share with others who share.

Comment: I get High Speed Internet and unlimited transmissions next week so all is fair game at that time. My WD My Cloud Mirror finally goes to work!! This week, I have such limited Internet I cannot read all the great links that are provided. Bye to all readers